# Custom Button in Material Bottom Tab Bar in react-native

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation

I have create material bottom tab bar and I want to add Custom button in which I have added but the button is showing half.

[image: Current View on Custom Button]

How can I show full round button. Tried with Position absolute still not working.

```
<Tab.Screen
      name="HomeBtn"
      component={HomeStackScreen}
      options={{
        tabBarIcon: () => (
          <View style={{
            position:'absolute',
            bottom:10,
            alignItems:'center',
            justifyContent: 'space-around',
            height:50,
            width:50,
            borderRadius: 25,
            backgroundColor:'green'
          }}>
          <MaterialCommunityIcons 
            name="barcode-scan"
            type = "material-community" 
            reverse
            color={'yellow'}
            reverseColor='black'
            containerStyle={{padding:0,margin:0,elevation:5}}
            onPress={()=>console.log('Hi')}
            size={30}/>
          
        </View>
        ),
      }}
    />
```

I tried with: Custom Compoent still same issue:

```
const CustomTab = ({ children, onPress }) => {
  return (
    <View style={{
      color: '#fff',
      alignItems: 'center',
      justifyContent: 'center',
      width: moderateScale(50),
      height: moderateScale(50),
      borderRadius: moderateScale(25),
      backgroundColor: '#62B250',
      marginBottom: moderateScale(60),
      marginHorizontal: moderateScale(5),
      top: -15,
      position: 'absolute'
    }}>
      <Text>
        <Icon name="add" style={{ color: '#fff', fontSize: 30 }} />
      </Text>
    </View>
  )
}
```

Both approaches have Same Issue i.e Half Button.

Comment: I think this will be helpful for you https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gPaBicMaib4

Comment: I saw that Video but the issue is if I Use that approach my screen content going behind my tab bar. and I have a lot of screens and I don't wanna mess with the Margin bottom on each screen.